# How to trace all sent request from one page in PHP?

Tags: php, post, get

How can I trace all sent (POST/GET) Request from one URL? As [Temper Data Add On](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) in firefox do.

For example, if I send a get/post request to `www.example.com` then I get a response from `www.example.com`. Now how I can get all requests (POST/GET) make by www.example.com.

Hope my question is clear.

NOTE:- I want to do all in PHP can compromise on JavaScript as well

Answer (score 0):

```
GET Request:
In GET request easy to traceable it passing into the your requesting URL such like this.

//example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578191/

where the above url value /45678191 is an GET value to sent the server.

POST Request:
In go to your network page -> header ->From data it shows all post value.form that page.
```

Comment: but how to trace all as the above plugin do